# Snippet to show prices with and without tax

Tags: php, woocommerce

I use this code to display prices with and without tax. Works well on single products, variations and "on sale" products as long as all variations have the "on sale" price.

If any variation dont have the "on sale" price, the snippet generates a fatal error.

Can any one help me to correct the code. Im no expert

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_price_prefix_suffix', 100, 2 );

function my_price_prefix_suffix( $price, $product ){ // To add suffix, go to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=tax

if ( $product->is_on_sale() )  {    
$price =  $price . ' c/IVA  |  '.wc_price($product->get_variation_sale_price()). ' s/IVA';
} elseif($product->is_type( 'variable' ) && $product->is_in_stock()){
    $price =  $price . ' c/IVA  |  '.wc_price($product->get_variation_regular_price()). ' s/IVA';
}

return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_price', $price );
}
```

I tryed the code above and i expect:

- That the product price apears with and without tax
- That the product sale apears with and without tax and the "normal" price apear with tax  striked

Comment: *"the snippet generates a fatal error."* what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it might be an issue related to your if / else statement.

Here you are checking to see if the product is on sale and if so, collecting the new price:

```
if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
$price = $price . ' c/IVA | '.wc_price($product->get_variation_sale_price()). ' s/IVA'; }
```

Here you are checking if, instead of being on sale, the product is in stock and is a variable type:

```
elseif($product->is_type( 'variable' ) && $product->is_in_stock()){ $price = $price . ' c/IVA | '.wc_price($product->get_variation_regular_price()). ' s/IVA'; }
```

So you are asking the program "Is this product on sale? If not, is it in stock & a variable type product?"

I believe you may want to structure this as

"Is product in stock?"
If so - is the product on sale?
If so - change the sale price
If else, display the regular price.

I am not very familiar with wooCommerce but it might be structured something like this:

```
if($product->is_type( 'variable' ) && $product->is_in_stock()){ 

  if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
    $price = $price . ' c/IVA | '.wc_price($product->get_variation_sale_price()). ' s/IVA'; 
  } else { 
    $price = $price . ' c/IVA | '.wc_price($product->get_variation_regular_price()). ' s/IVA'; 
  }
}
```